# Installing Photoshop CC on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wine, playonlinux, photoshop

I am trying to install Photoshop CC on Ubuntu 14.04. I downloaded Wine and Playonlinux. I selected Photoshop CS6 (in description it says it is also choice for CC) and started to install it. However an error appeared saying 'This product can only be installed on a 64-bit system.' It gave me only option to close it. After that Playonlinux loaded something and gave me another error 'Error in POL_Shortcut Binary not found: photoshop.exe Have you installed the program to the default location?'

Comment: Sorry I have no time to properly answer, but look for WINE PREFIX, where you can set wine to be 64bits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never figured out how to properly install CC version of Photoshop on Linux. Even tho I successfully installed it, it was buggy. However, for a while now, I am using Photoshop CS6 on Linux (Kubuntu 16.04, Gubuntu 17.04) without many troubles:

I found this answer helpful:

https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-install-photoshop-CS6-on-ubuntu#

Which I quote from:

```
Vandolph C. Reyes, Full Stack Web Developer
Updated Oct 3, 2016
```

> I’m using ubuntu 16.04 and I just installed cs6 few months ago. It was
>   very tricky and very hard because most of the tutorials from the
>   internet doesn’t work for me until I find my own solution.
>
> Most tutorials are using complete file or installer of photoshop. In
>   my version I only tried the portable and it works for me.
>
> 1: Download the executable file. I forgot where I downloaded this file
>   so I will just upload and share it you. Check this link
>   https://mega.nz/#!qMs3xRKA!PQmHq...
>
> 2: Install wine - http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/12/install-wine-1-8-stable-new-ppa/
>
> 3: Install playonlinux PlayOnLinux - https://blogs.pennmanor.net/1to1/2014/10/28/playonlinux/
>
> 4: Install the cs6 using play on linux
>    4.1 click install a program
>    4.2 search for adobe photoshop cs6
>    4.3 then choose the portable file and install (remember where you installed the photoshop)

At this point everything was working fine for me, but in case you get some errors, this might help:

> After this, you will be able to install photoshop but here’s the
>   tricky part. During the installation, it will show you that
>   installation was just keep on going even though you already running
>   it. But after you close the photoshop, it was not installed on
>   playonlinux and you can’t run it from it’s directory.
>
> But here’s what solution I found.
>
> - 4.3.1 open playonlinux
> - 4.3.2 click “configure” on top-right
> - 4.3.3 select “photoshopcs6” on the top-left
> - 4.3.4 then click “miscellaneous” on the last tab
> - 4.3.5 lastly, click “Run a .exe file in this virtual drive” and locate the directory of the installed photoshop and select the .exe
>
> And your done. Disadvantage: You always need to follow the steps from
>   4.3.1 everytime you want to open the cs6. It’s very hassle but atleast, currently I satisfied with my photoshop. Here’s my screenshot
>   taken few minutes ago. I hope it works in your end too. Goodluck.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [The official guide on installing Photoshop using wine](http://wiki.winehq.org/AdobePhotoshop)

Also if you are unable to get Photoshop and are looking for an alternative use [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/). Gimp comes with some versions of Ubuntu and is a very comprehensive photo editing tool

Hope this helps,

Zimbinskers